# rawQuery() in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a sql query like this:

```
   String loadFav = "SELECT Aid FROM  Author_table where " + " Author_name= 'Sultan' ";
   Cursor result2 = db.rawQuery(loadFav, null);
```

But I get exception for this piece of code . Is there any reason for getting exception ? Where is my error ?

Comment: Could you add the logcat pls?

Comment: your error is in logcat ...

Comment: whenever you want to access the db you need to initialize the Database and you need to call the method db.getReadable or db.getWritable().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String loadFav = "SELECT Aid FROM  Author_table where ...";
Cursor result2 = db.rawQuery(loadFav, null);
```

Most likely your error is thrown because your `SQLiteDatabase` is assigned to `NULL`. Make sure that you call before it

```
db = helper.getWritableDatabase(); // or getReadableDatabase()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer to your question (I guess Sajmon right), but consider to use parametrized queries instead of yours, it's more safe and efficient:

```
String[] whereCriteria = new String[] {"Sultan"};
String query ="SELECT Aid FROM  Author_table where Author_name=?";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, whereCriteria);
```

Comment: yeah . I will try to make my code efficient .